# nested ng-repeat isn't working properly

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to call a double nested ng-repeat to cycle through objects in objects, and it just doesn't work. I'm using tables (tr, td)

This is my HTML code:

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in rows">
  <td ng-repeat="item in row">
     {{item}}
  </td>
</tr>
```

And this is my data object:

```
$scope.rows = [["10:00", "0"],["12:00","1"]]
```

But the table doesn't print anything. What I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

**UPDATE**

The stackoverflow example works fine, sorry.

With my data original array doesn't work:

```
[["10:00","0","0","3","0","0","0","0"],    
["12:00","0","0","3","0","0","0","0"], 
["14:00","0","0","3","0","0","0","0"],
["16:00","0","0","3","0","0","0","0"],
["18:00","0","0","3","0","0","0","0"],
["20:00","0","0","3","0","0","0","0"],
["22:00","0","0","3","0","0","0","0"]]
```

I want to create something like:

[image]

Comment: Is the table not being printed at all (no tr or td tags) or is it just the {{item}} modal that is not being populated?

Comment: it works for me if you remove the acute i (í) in `ítem` and use `item` instead

Comment: The ng-repeat is not creating the td

Comment: @user2341963 sorry, the acute i was a mistake!! With normal i isnt working neither

Comment: it also works for me, do you have a `<table>` tag wrapped around the `<tr>` ?

Comment: Do you have `ng-app` and `ng-controller` defined? See [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/xziLaQn1YXzRXHDTpj1f?p=preview)

Comment: It is strange, javascript identifiers are unicode but (í) in identifier makes problem.

Comment: you have duplicate data in your inner repeater.  you will have to use `track by` in order to iterate that data;  there should be an error in the console informing you of that fact.  try `ng-repeat="item in row track by $index"`

Comment: @Claies You should add that as an answer, it sounds to me like the problem.

Comment: CORRECT! Please @Claies add your answer to close the question

Comment: I was working on the answer, just needed to ensure that I had the plunker before posting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When running your code with your sample data exactly as shown, the following error is noted in the console logs:

> `Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys. Repeater: item in row, Duplicate key: string:0, Duplicate value: 0`

This can be resolved by adding a `track by` expression to your `ng-repeat`.  Since you don't have a specific column in the data to use as an index, you can use the `$index` special property of `ng-repeat`.

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in rows">
  <td ng-repeat="item in row track by $index">
     {{item}}
  </td>
</tr>
```

This code will give you the expected output.

http://plnkr.co/edit/aSbaom85JsQwUfTIwKk3?p=preview